# Programmatically Generating WebControls

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that, depending on input from a previous page, lists a varying number of different questions pulled from a database. I can't seem to find an example of this online: For each question that is displayed, I need to programmatically generate a DropDownList so that the user can select yes or no for each of these questions. Hoping someone here can give me some direction on where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to use the Repeater control with a template that just contains the dropdownlist with static list items.  Something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="questionRepeater">
<HeaderTemplate>
  //some html
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<div align=center>
<asp:Label runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"questionColumn")%></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
   <asp:ListItem text="No" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in your code behind, you can execute your query and bind the results to the repeater.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
    SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("Server=server;UID=uid;PWD=password;Database=whatever");  
   string sSQL = "Select questionColumn from Questions";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conDotNet);   
   db.Open();  
   SqlDataReader dtrCat = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
   questionRepeater.DataSource = dtrCat;  
  questionRepeater.DataBind();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is pseudo, but may help...

```
//essentially, run through loop of questions and for each
//add the question and yes/no stuff..
///PlaceHolder is a ContentPlaceholder Control within the .aspx page.
foreach(inputtype input in this.inputs)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = input.Question;

    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = input.QuestionID;
    ddl.DataSource = YesNoDataTable;
    ddl.DataBind();

    this.PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lbl);
    this.PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ddl);
}
```

Comment: Womps suggestion on the repeater control is probably better if the only thing that changes is indeed the question.  But if you had "types" of questions that triggered different response mechanisms, say an int, then you probably would need something like this...

Comment: by different response mechanisms, I'm suggesting that maybe you have an input that only allows an int, maybe one that is a yes/no, maybe one that list colors, etc.

Comment: Yeah womp's method is more suited to my problem, but only by chance as I didn't explain much in detail in the question, but thanks for sharing this method. I'd never seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim tDropDownList As DropDownList = Nothing
Dim tQuestion As String = String.Empty

For Each tQuestion In tQuestions
    tDropDownList = New DropDownList
    tDropDownList.Name = "someName here"
    tDropDownList.Items.Add("Yes")
    tDropDownList.Items.Add("No")
    Page.Constrols.Add(tDropDownList)
Next
```